# Thorough equality testing of two maps with googletest

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

I am wondering what the "correct/best" way to test equality of two `std::map`s using the googletest framework is?

The catch is that the `std::map` has some pointers in the values and I want to test that the thing they point to is correct across the two `std::map`s.

For example my map has the following signature:

```cpp
std::map<int, std::vector<std::pair<MyClass1*, MyClass2*>>>
```

So I want to make sure the values of `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` pointers are the same across the two maps I am testing.

Comment: Just define `bool operator==(const YourMap& lhs, const YourMap& rhs)` and google test will use it in `ASSERT_EQ`. Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: Yeah, this is how I am doing it at the moment. But it feels very "hacky". If this is indeed the best way then so be it, but I was hoping to find a cleaner, better-tested method using gtest.

Comment: This was discussed in many places and I don't see any clear conclusion: [google style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Operator_Overloading), [gtest docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md#binary-comparison). You can always do `ASSERT_TRUE(mapsEqual(map1, map2))`, but if you have in mind some clear strategy for comparison of your types, just define `operator==`. It's not hacky, just depends on your application.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a matcher if `operator==` is not an option:

```
using mymap = std::map<int, std::vector<std::pair<MyClass1 *, MyClass2 *>>>;

MATCHER_P(MAP_MATCHER, expected_map, "Maps are not equal") {
  if (expected_map.size() != arg.size()) {
    return false;
  }
  return std::all_of(expected_map.cbegin(), expected_map.cend(), [&](const std::pair<int, std::vector<std::pair<MyClass1 *, MyClass2 *>>> &item) {
  auto arg_item = arg.find(item.first);
    if (arg.cend() == arg_item) {
      return false;
    }
    //more checks here
  });
}
```

And then use it:

```
TEST(maptest, test1) {
  mymap m1{{1, {{new MyClass1{}, new MyClass2{}}}}};
  mymap m2{{1, {{new MyClass1{}, new MyClass2{}}}}};

  ASSERT_THAT(m1, MAP_MATCHER(m2));
}
```